# Printing N times 'a' and N times 'b' using a Recursive function in Java

Tags: java, function, recursion

So, the following recursive function in C:

```
void print(int n){
    if(n==1){
       printf("ab");
     return;
    }
     putchar('a');
     print(n-1);
     putchar('b');
 }
```

will give you the output: `aaabbb` if n=3.
But, i tried to 'translate' this into Java and came up with a problem.
my code in Java looks like this: (which is pretty similar)

```
   public static void printAB(int n){
        if (n==1) {
            System.out.println("ab");
        }else {
            System.out.print("a");
            printAB(n-1);
            System.out.print("b");
        }
    }
```

but the output i'm getting is this:

```
aaab
bb
```

no matter what i tried i couldn't fix the last 2 'b' to be in the same line.

help please?

Comment: `println()` prints a new line at the end.

Comment: OMG. i did not think about that. ty so much !

Comment: Off topic but I would prefer `fputs("ab", stdout);` to `printf("ab");` in C, since there are no format specifiers in the string. Not that it matters, really. (You can't use `puts` here for the same reason you don't want to use `println` in Java.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
System.out.println("ab");
```

to:

```
System.out.print("ab");
```

so there is no newline printed.

**Full Code:**

```
public static void printAB(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        System.out.print("ab");
    } else {
        System.out.print("a");
        printAB(n - 1);
        System.out.print("b");
    }
}
```

**Output for `printAB(3)`:**

```
aaabbb
```